Lazy-loading modules with SSR angular 17
I'm using angular 17 with SSR. now the issue is I have some routes that lazy loading modules, and these modules are loaded from different libraries. The issue I'm facing is these modules are not loaded on the server side.
To verify this issue, I also saw when I opened these routes and saw the page source HTML of those modules is not there, which means it's not loaded on the server side, hence loaded on the client side.
This my  route.js file:
import { Routes, UrlMatchResult, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';
import { TabMetaDataResolver } from './shared/inteceptors/tab-metadata-resolver';
import { defaultTabs, TabKeyEnum, SubTypeEnum } from "ngx-exdr-stmx-common";


export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadComponent: () => import('./layout/pages-layout/pages-layout.component').then(c => c.PagesLayoutComponent),
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                loadComponent: () => import('./layout/home/home.component').then(c => c.HomeComponent)
            },
            {
                path: defaultTabs[TabKeyEnum.Chat], // For following enums Chat & Language, both have same endpoint
                loadComponent: () => import('./coming-soon/coming-soon.component').then(c => c.ComingSoonComponent),
            },
            {
                path: defaultTabs[TabKeyEnum.Blogs],
                loadChildren: () => import('ngx-pxdr-ptmx-idpdi/blogs').then(m => m.BlogsModule),
                data: {
                  tabKey: TabKeyEnum.Blogs
                }
            },
            {
            {
                path: defaultTabs[TabKeyEnum.Library],
                // path: 'test-product',
                data: {
                  tabKey: TabKeyEnum.Library
                },                        
                loadChildren: () => import('ngx-pxdr-ptmx-techmeAk').then(m => m.ProductsModule)
            },
            {
                path: '**',
                //redirectTo: ''
                loadComponent: () => import('./coming-soon/coming-soon.component').then(c => c.ComingSoonComponent),
            },                    
            
        ]        
        .map((r: any) => {
            let obj: any = { metaData: TabMetaDataResolver };                  
            if (!r.resolve) {
              r.resolve = obj;
            } else {
              r.resolve['metaData'] = TabMetaDataResolver;
            }
            return r;
          })
    },
    //add route that will be used to navigate to if route not found
];

What might be the issue or it's normal behavior for ssr?
